Why does it tell me that the value property of target does not exist if all html elements have a value?
I am doing a project related to API and I am using Angular, Angular Material, Typescrit and RXJS, the error is when trying to highlight a search bar, in this fragment of html code I get the error seen in the image
this is the complete html5
div id="pagina">
  <br>
  <br>
  <video src="../../../../assets/videos/background-video.mp4" autoplay loop muted  type="video/mp4"></video>
  <div id="titulo">
    <h1>LOS CAMPEONES</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>Conoce a los campeones de las distintas regiones de Runeterra.</h2>
    <blockquote>¡Haz click en el botón saber más para descubrir más detalles o busca a tu campeón favorito!</blockquote>
  </div>
  <div id="separador">
    <img src="../../../../assets/images/decorator-hr-lg.png" alt="decorator-hr">
  </div>
  <div id="busqueda">

    <mat-form-field class="buscar">
      <input class="campo" type="text" matInput placeholder="Buscar un campeón" aria-label="Buscar un campeón"
      (keyup)="searchChampion.next($event.target?.value)">
      <!--cada vez que se presione una teclla(on key up s) se envia/emite ael valor de esa letra presionada
      ($even.target.value)y   $event es para manejar eventos (con esto manejo onkeyup), atarget es 
    la propiedad de event (equivale ha hacer un document.getElement  , document.querySelector, 
    es el DOM de angular , mas bien es el elemnto que disparo ese evento (la tecla pulsada valla)
    avalue es el valor del target p es p r es r lol es lol) 
  modo resumido cada vez que el usuario presiona una tecla y levanta el dedo(keyup) se searchCampion
lo emite(next), es decir se emite el valor de la tecla que el usuario pulse
funciona gracias a rxjs principalmente-->
      <button mat-button matSuffix>
        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>

  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <ng-template ngIf="isLoad">
      <div class="cartas" *ngFor="let champion of champions ">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-header id="campeones">

            <img mat-card-image [alt]="champion.name" [src]="'../../../../assets/img/icons/'+champion.name+'.jpeg'">
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>

            <mat-card-title id="nombre"><h3>{{champion.name}}</h3></mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>


and this is the typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LolService } from '../../services/lol.service';
import {Datum } from '../../interfaces/champions.interface';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'card-component',
  templateUrl: './card-component.component.html',
  styleUrl: './card-component.component.scss'
})
export class CardComponent{
  isLoad=false;
  searchChampion=new Subject<string>();//esto servira para manejar los eventos del buscador a apartir de obserables
  champions:Datum[]=[];
  championsFilter:Datum[]=[];//esto lo usare para filtar campeones en la barra de busqueda

  constructor(private lolService:LolService ){
  this.obtenerInfo();
  }
  searchChampions():void{//estafuncion  es para buscar por nombre
    this.searchChampion.subscribe(key =>{//el subject search champion se suscribe a cada observable que emite en cardcomponent html
      
      this.championsFilter = this.champions.filter(champ => champ.name.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase()));
      //despues lo va filtrandon  y guardando en un  arreglo  de objetos
      //de cada campeon (cada objeto del array ) coje el nombre(la propiedad name de cada objeto) la vuelve minuscula(uso la funcion toLoweCase para poner el nombre de cada la propiedad name de cada objeto champion del arreglo champions   en miniscula )
      //despues uso include para combaprobar si el nombre recibido(el string key convertido en minusculas) es gual al nombre del campeon actual(a la propiedad name del objeto actual champ)
    })
  }

  obtenerInfo(){
    this.lolService.obtenerChampInfo()
    .subscribe( champion=>{

      console.log(Object.values(champion.data))//
     this.champions=Object.values(champion.data);
      console.log(this.champions)
      this.isLoad=true
      // for (let champion of this.champions){ //para que no se me pete la memoria con las descargas al hacer un cambio u otro
      //   let url='https://gameriv.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/'+champion.name+'-Icon.jpeg'
      //   let nombreImagen:string=champion.name+'.jpeg';
      //   this.lolService.descargarImg(url,nombreImagen)
      //   console.log('imagen descargada')
      // }
    })
  }
}


How i can fix the error?
I put it optional because first it told me that it could be null


this is the complete html5: well, that's a problem. Please familiarize yourself with the notion of minimal, complete, reproducible example.

Not all valid event targets are HTML elements (e.g. web workers). And not all HTML Elements have a .value property, see e.g. this . It's unclear why you think that's the case.

Okay I understand not all html5 events have value, so what should I use instead, I have followed the tutorial on this page, but nevertheless he does not get any errors https://wilderperozo.medium.com/buscador-din%C3%A1mico-usando-angular-y-rxjs-ba94645ea862

@Quenuo the answer by Naren Murali is fine.

For this particular scenario, it's best you wrap $any(). This is the HTML equivalent of setting as any type, the event (TypeDefinition) does not have value we know it has a value (actual object).
<input class="campo" type="text" placeholder="Buscar un campeón" aria-label="Buscar un campeón"
  (keyup)="searchChampion.next($any($event.target).value)">

Stackblitz Demo

An alternative will be to just define a method, which will wrap the target and perform the same action.
Here I use TypeScript intersection operator & to define the type as EventTarget and also has a value property of any type and assigned it to a type Target. We can use this to get rid of the error:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

export type Target = EventTarget & { value: string };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <input class="campo" type="text" placeholder="Buscar un campeón" aria-label="Buscar un campeón"
      (keyup)="searchChampionEvent($event)">
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  searchChampion = new Subject<string>();

  searchChampionEvent(event: Event) {
    const stringValue = (event.target as Target)?.value ?? '';
    this.searchChampion.next(stringValue);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

...why use any instead of string? Any value of an HTML form control is going to be a string...

@JaredSmith Input has multiple types, string, number, date. but anyway updating it!

...the value attribute of an HTMLInputElement is always a string, even for numeric inputs.

Minor nitpick, you could also simplify a bit more by using nullish coalescing instead of the nullish access operator: (event.target as Target).value ?? '';.

not familiar with rxjs but assuming it just uses the DOM types, and event target, and currentTarget, are potentially null.
Can see spec here https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#determining-the-target-of-an-event-handler
So the types just follow that, anything you want to do more specific than that you would have to implement yourself and you can assert the values are non null using some abstraction, but many times its also to either check the value or just assert its non null on usage.
As a simple example, if you absolutely know the value can never be null then instead of
searchChampion.next($event.target?.value)

You can use
searchChampion.next($event.target!.value)


I tried that but i have the same error

You shouldn't pass value directly to property, because it make your component messy. Better way is to create new method and then pass value to your property.
Something like this:
someMethod(event: Event): void {
  const target = <HTMLInputElement>event.target;
  this.searchChampion.next(target.value);
}

You need to clarify for TS from what element you are trying to get value because it doesn't know.

This is completely unsafe. You are asserting to the compiler that something that at best might be an HTML element that isn't a form control is one, and at worst might be null or undefined and blow up at runtime. If you're going to ignore all the error paths, why use Typescript at all?

What are you talking about? You just specify from what tag you are getting your data... Where is that safe when you assign it as any? xD

"You just specify from what tag you are getting your data" again, the point of using Typescript is that the compiler shows you where you don't do a good enough job of checking what something is. If you don't care and just want to call null a HTMLInputElement because you hate your users, why even bother?

But with that approach I have always string as a value, so where is your null?

What if event.target.value is undefined? What if the event is from something that isn't an HTMLInput and therefor doesn't have a .value property? Using a type cast the way you are is something you do only when you know beyond a shadow of a doubt, something that the compiler can't prove. You are making assumptions about the event.target, assumptions that might be wrong, and the compiler is trying to tell you that. If you're response to it's helpful suggestion is to just tell it "shut up, I know what I'm doing" then why bother using Typescript at all?
